# what is the difference between __weak UIImage *image and UIImage *__weak image in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, weak

What is the difference between `__weak UIImage *image and UIImage *__weak image` in iOS ? And is the __weak necessary with ARC ?

I have seen this code pattern in may examples wherein the UIImage is created programmatically in iOS but, is this pattern still necessary ? Ad also what is the difference between putting it before UIImage and after the pointer *

And for the record I am not asking about strong vs weak, I am asking about the whether __weak is necessary in the case I mentioned and if so does it have anything to do with the placement of __weak. As an example

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.bounds.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [label.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *__weak icon = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: nope it's not a duplicate of strong vs weak... I am asking about something else here

Comment: Even the subject of the referred Q is different, you will find the solution there. To make it short: There is no difference.

Comment: Do we still need to provide __weak for ARC enabled code base ?

Comment: Yes, *only* for ARC enabled code. You will find tons of Qs related to this topic and it is documented.